# Join conditions in awk

Tags: shell, awk, grep, conditional-statements

How can I join this command

```
top -b -n 5 -d.2 | grep "Cpu" |  awk 'NR==3{ print($2)}'
```

into only awk command (joining grep and awk into one) ?

I have tried this but with no success:

```
top -b -n 5 -d.2 | awk '{if( $1 == "Cpu(s):" && NR==3 ){ print($2)} }'
```

or

```
top -b -n 5 -d.2 | awk '{$1 ~ /Cpu/ && (NR==3) { print($2)}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
top -b -n 5 -d.2 | awk '/Cpu/ { if (++cnt==3) print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/Cpu/ {x++; if(x==3) { print $2}}'
```

Note: you can add `exit` for short-circuiting.